# Encrypt a small file using openssl and a DER formatted public key

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

I used openssl to create a private/public key pair:

```
  openssl req -x509 -out public_key.der -outform der -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650
```

Because I wanted to use [XRSA](https://github.com/xjunior/XRSA) from Github, I generated the public key in DER format, as the library's author suggested.

However, when I try to encrypt a file using the public_key.der file, I get "unable to load Public Key". I've tried the following:

```
$ openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey public_key.der -encrypt -in input.txt 
unable to load Public Key
$ openssl rsautl -pubin -keyform DER  -inkey public_key.der -encrypt -in input.txt 
unable to load Public Key
```

In fact, I've tried many other permutations of the above options, always getting the same error.

Can someone show me how to encrypt a small text file using the public_key.der file I've generated?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please ask a new question. There is already an answer. You cannot change the question and include the answer. It would make the answer obsolete and future readers would not understand why the answer was given since it is included in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you used for generating is intended for generating self-signed certificates.

Try these commands to generate a RSA keypair:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -out public.der -outform der
```

And then this to encrypt the file:

```
openssl rsautl -pubin -keyform der -inkey public.der -encrypt -in input.txt
```

Comment: thanks. Now my problem is trying to use the DER to create a cert object in objective c. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ObjC specifics.